# Unknown type name 'MyAppPushNotificationHandler'

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm creating a react native app, but need to make some adjustments in native iOS code to support push notifications when integrating a CRM system.

I've created a swift file (according to the guide [here](https://customer.io/docs/sdk/react-native/push/)) that's bridged to Object-C code.

The Swift file is imported like this: #import `"app-Swift.h"`

and declared like this `MyAppPushNotificationsHandler* pnHandlerObj = [[MyAppPushNotificationsHandler alloc] init];`

If I:

- add it directly after the `"app-Swift.h"` I get the error  `Use of undeclared identifier 'pnHandlerObj'` further down in the file where I'm using it
- if I add it just above the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
  (below @interface and @implementation AppDelegate) I get the two
  errors `Use of undeclared identifier 'MyAppPushNotificationsHandler'` and `Unknown type name 'MyAppPushNotificationsHandler'`

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the file is not being imported properly. Based on this line `#import "app-Swift.h"` I can conclude that the `Product Name` of your app is `app`. Maybe that's incorrect, you should be sure that you're using the correct `Product Name`. To check the `Product Name` of your app go to `Targets > Build Settings`:

[image]

The `Product Name` on this specific image is `AutolayoutDemoView`. So in this instance you would import the Swift file inside of `AppDelegate.m` like this:

```
#import "AutolayoutDemoView-Swift.h"
```

**Another note**

The guide tells you to initialize the class `MyAppPushNotificationsHandler` outside of any function, like this:

```
MyAppPushNotificationsHandler* pnHandlerObj = [[MyAppPushNotificationsHandler alloc] init];

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
...
```

But if you do that, you will get the following error: ***Initializer element is not a compile-time constant***

So to get rid of that error, you should initialize the `MyAppPushNotificationsHandler` inside of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 { 
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
   UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
   rootViewController.view = rootView;
   self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   
   // Register for push notifications
   MyAppPushNotificationsHandler* pnHandlerObj = [[MyAppPushNotificationsHandler alloc] init];
   [pnHandlerObj registerPushNotification:self];
   return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Yes, the Product name is app, so that shouldn't cause the errors. 
Inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I had added this before: `[pnHandlerObj registerPushNotification:self];`. But I changed it and tried your way but then I get the same errors; `Unknown type name 'MyAppPushNotificationHandler` and `Use of undeclared identifier 'MyAppPushNotifcationHandler'`

Comment: @AmandaDahlin have you added the `Bridging-Header-h` file then?

Comment: Yes, I do. It autogenerated that one. Do I need to add anything in it?

Comment: @AmandaDahlin Nope, you don't have to add anything in it. You could also try importing the file like this: `#import <app-Swift.h>` or you could just write `#import <` and then press `CTRL + SPACE` to get autocompletion results. You could go through the results and see if you can find the `-Swift.h` file

Comment: It didn't appear in the list but it showed up when I started typing once. And once the import is in place the import doesn't show any errors so it seems that it finds the file.

Comment: Then you should check if your Swift file is okay. Does it contain the `@objc` decorator above the `MyAppPushNotificationsHandler` class and all of the functions except`init`? Is the class inheriting `NSObject`?

Comment: Yes, it contains the `@objc` decorator. I copied the file from this section in the CRM [guide](https://www.customer.io/docs/sdk/react-native/push/#obj-c-push)

Comment: In order to get rid of `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant` error follow this piece of doc (https://customer.io/docs/sdk/react-native/push/#error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)